# codigniter inserting multiple values to database not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have a simple codeigniter form , where there is a checkbox like below:

```html
 <th>  <input class="acb" type="checkbox"  name="generateawb[]" value="<?=$val->id?>" onclick="deRequire('acb')" required /></th>
  <button type="submit" name="savemedaa" style="margin-left:5px; font-size: 0.6em; " class="btn btn-warning">GENERATE AWB</button>
```

so when the user selects either one or multiple checkboxes, it should insert the selected datas to another table, my controller is like below:

```html
public function generateawb() {
  $data = array();
    if(isset($_POST['savemedaa']))
    {

      $checkboxs = $_POST['generateawb'];
      $generateawb = $this->excel_import_model->selectawb($checkboxs);

foreach($generateawb as $row){
  $clientid= $row->id;
  $batchnumber= $row->batchnumber;

}
$awbg = random_int(100000000, 999999999);
$awb='LRG'.$awbg;

        $data[] = array(
          'clientid'=>$clientid,
          'awb'=>$awb,
           'batchnumber'=>$batchnumber,

        );

      $this->excel_import_model->generateawb($data);

    }
      }
}
```

and my model is like below:

```html
    public function selectawb($checkboxs) {
                            $this->db->select('*');
                            $this->db->where_in("id", $checkboxs);
                            $this->db->from('fileupload');
                         $query = $this->db->get();
                         $result = $query->result();
                         return $result;

                        }

                        function generateawb($data){
                            $this->db->insert_batch('consignments', $data);
                        }
```

now the issue is, even if user selects multiple checkboxes only one checkbox is saved to database, can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting $data[] outside the foreach so it has only one value. Just put it inside:

```
public function generateawb()
    {
        $data = array();
        if (isset($_POST['savemedaa'])) {

            $checkboxs = $_POST['generateawb'];
            $generateawb = $this->excel_import_model->selectawb($checkboxs);

            foreach ($generateawb as $row) {
                $clientid = $row->id;
                $batchnumber = $row->batchnumber;
                $awbg = random_int(100000000, 999999999);
                $awb = 'LRG' . $awbg;

                $data[] = array(
                    'clientid' => $clientid,
                    'awb' => $awb,
                    'batchnumber' => $batchnumber,

                );
            }

            $this->excel_import_model->generateawb($data);
        }
    }
```

You should use a formatter to avoid errors like this. If you use VSCode you can use this [extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense)